# How to assure that only explicit characters in given list are used by def in Python?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a small code using "def" to create my own function in Python. This function checks if a string provided by a user is a DNA sequence or not. Since DNA can be composed only of acids abbreviated as A, C, G, T my function should accept only strings composed of this letters and return True otherwise it must return False. My code is doing that to some extent but in some cases like 'ACGTGATTCGF' or 'CGGCGAACCACCaxCCAzAatccG' or ' " ' it returns True instead of False. I do not understand why. Here is the code:

```
def is_this_dna(sequence):
    acids = ["A", "C", "G", "T"]
    for c in sequence:
        if c in acids:
            return True
        else:
            return False

#code driver
my_dna = str(input("Enter your DNA sequence:"))

print(is_this_dna(my_dna))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code that you are checking only the first character. After checking it, you have return in both cases.

Try instead:

```
def is_this_dna(sequence):
    acids = ["A", "C", "G", "T"]
    for c in sequence:
        if c not in acids:
            return False
    return True and len(sequence)>0
```

In this code, you will return `True` only after you checked all the characters and the sequence is not an empty string.

Another solution might be:

```
def is_this_dna(sequence):
    acids = ["A", "C", "G", "T"]
    return len(sequence)>0 and all([c in acids for c in sequence])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're returning `True` straight away as soon as you find one the acids characters in your string before checking all the elements

Something like this should work.

```
def is_this_dna(sequence):
   acids = ["A", "C", "G", "T"]
   return all(c in acids for c in sequence)
```

Another version could be. (I think the first one is more idiomatic though)

```
def is_this_dna(sequence):
   acids = ["A", "C", "G", "T"]
   for c in sequence:
       if c not in acids:
           return False
   return True
```

Comment: @Lucka Romagnoli Thank you for your help. I understand now bit better.

Comment: However there is still problem when the string is empty it returns True instead of False

Comment: Yeah you should check that edge case beforehand and return False straight away. My name is Luca btw :-)

Comment: Thanks again Luca :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `acids` a set instead to test if it is a superset of the input sequence:

```
def is_this_dna(sequence):
    return {"A", "C", "G", "T"}.issuperset(sequence)
```